# VBA charts not refreshing with refresh.all or if I loop through the charts

Tags: excel, vba, refresh, excel-charts, ontime

Hello I am trying to write a script that will call a function to refresh charts every 30 seconds. The first function provided works by simply telling the machine to run my other function "RefreshCharts" after 30 seconds. The problem I am having in my RefreshCharts sub however is that the charts do not refresh when I run the script. First I just had a function that just had refresh.all in it but that wasn't updating the charts even though when I recorded a macro in excel that's what it gave me and it worked then but doesn't when I update the data (the data is pulled from a separate sheet) right now I tried to loop through each chart in the workbook and tried to see if they would update if I wrote that they should refresh in the loop but still they don't update. Below is the code I am using any help would be appreciated.

```
Sub myTime()

    Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:00:30"), "RefreshCharts"


End Sub

Sub RefreshCharts()

    Workbooks.Open Filename:="C:\Users\mansah57\Desktop\Malek Excel\refresh\2019 EXCEL Filling Daily Production Tracking.xlsx"
    Dim myChart As ChartObject
    For Each myChart In ThisWorkbook.Charts
        myChart.Chart.Refresh
        'Debug.Print "hit"
    Next myChart
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Workbooks("2019 EXCEL Filling Daily Production Tracking.xlsx").Close SaveChanges:=False
    Call myTime

End Sub
```

Comment: Are they normal charts or pivot charts?  If they are normal charts, there is nothing to refresh, as soon as the data changes, the chart changes.  If they are pivot charts, try refreshing the pivot tables.

Comment: Aside: If you need to do this every 30 seconds, do you have to open/close that file every time?